# Oracle Apex: Change page content based on changing select list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I create a page with 2 select lists and a report as follows:

- Select List1: 1 - 12 (Month of year)
- Select List2: 2010 - 2015 (Year from 2010 to 2015)
- Report: Get data from view GET_DATA_SALARY. This view has 4 column: NAME, SALARY, FAC_MONTH, FAC_YEAR
- Report to be refreshed based on the values of the 2 select lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create two select item for 'Month' & 'Year' (Like, P1_MONTH_ITEM and P1_YEAR_ITEM).

2) Create new report with the query let's say,

```
SELECT NAME, SALARY, FAC_MONTH, FAC_YEAR FROM GET_DATA_SALARY WHERE 
FAC_MONTH = :P1_MONTH_ITEM AND FAC_YEAR = :P1_YEAR_ITEM
```

3) `Most important`: In report find "Page Items to Submit" and provide your Items (i.e. P1_MONTH_ITEM and P1_YEAR_ITEM), These items will be passed as  parameter in dynamic refresh.

4) Create `Dynamic Action` -> Provide DA name

-> Event = "Change", Selection Type = "Item(s)", Items(s) = Select both Month and Year Item (P1_MONTH_ITEM,P1_YEAR_ITEM)

-> Action = "Refresh", Selection Type = "Region", Region = "your report region"